# Position an icon inside textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position an icon that should clear the `textarea` content. I have a sample I worked on, wrapped the textarea with a parent that has `display: inline-block` but the problem is that I want the textarea/parent to be full width to begin with. If I set a 100% width on textarea, it does not achieve the desired result. Also, can't work with `vw` which seems to work apparently, for some reason people at work avoid it.

Here's what I have

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-haze-ncslb?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Post your code in the question. Stackoverflow has runnable snipplets

Comment: Why does it have to be inline-block if you want the width to be 100% anyways?

Comment: Unclear what the issue is with the code. Set he width to the wrapper or make the wrapper a block element.

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) (icon looks like `<>` in a page on the editor toolbar) to include a [mre] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either change `.parent` class to `display:block` or add the 2 lines `width: 100%;  box-sizing: border-box;` in css as demonstrated below:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  
  width: 100%;            /*Add this line*/
  box-sizing: border-box; /*Add this line*/
  
}

.parent span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.parent textarea {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

I have added code to make the parent div resizable as per the textarea. However I don't know any other method to do this without using `vw` for the text area.

```css
    .parent {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;     
      width: fit-content; /*not supported in IE */
    }
    
    .parent span {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 6px;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .parent textarea {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: none;
      width: calc(100vw - 40px);
      display: block;      
    }
```

```html
 
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <span>X</span>
  </div>
</body>
```